# Не получается правильно отсортировать массив

Tags: c++, visual-studio

По заданию сказано что надо отсортировать по возрастанию **3-тий столбец** массива, используя сортировку **вставкой**. 
Написал сортировку. Ошибок как таковых не обнаружено, но и при выводе "отсортированного" столбца выводит крякозябры 
Вот моя сортировка:

```
template<class T>
void insertSort(T arr[], long size)
{
T x;
long i, j;
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    x=arr[i];
    for(j=i-1; j>=0 && arr[j]>x; j--)
        arr[j+1]=arr[j];
    arr[j+1]=x;
}
}
```

Ну а вот вывод якобы отсортированного столбца который мне нужен:

```
insertSort(arr, n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=2; j<3; j++)
    {
        cout<<setw(7)<<arr[j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь
[image: вот что выводит]

Вывод 3-го столбца у меня такой:

```
int* arr=new int[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=2; j<3; j++)
    {
        cout<<setw(7)<<a[i][j];
        arr[j]=a[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Вы сортируете не содержимое массива, а адреса

Comment: А где именно я ошибся??

Comment: @razorqhex: А какой именно тип `T` у вас получается?

Comment: @Abyx
Под скриншотом код

Comment: @VladD
Код я брал с интернета и отредактировал. особого объяснения там не было :( единственная сортировка которая для меня самая нормальна это пузырьковая сортировка.

Comment: @razorqhex: Это не оправдание. Вы предоставляете код — вы за него отвечаете. Прикиньте, если на работе ваш код закрешится, а вы скажете начальнику «я скопировал с инета без понимания сути, спрашивайте с автора кода».

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй выводить тот же массив что ты сортируешь, а не вновь созданный заполненный мусором.

```
int* arr = new int[n];
```